# Add field to an entity_view for dispaly in a tapir table in ubercart

Tags: theming, ubercart

In the simplest terms I am trying to add a 'vendor' column to the order view table in Ubercart which will display the author of each line item product.

Below is the table of interest.  I have hacked the direct code contained in `uc_order.order_pane.inc` but will refactor with hooks the drupal way ASAP. I have added my comments in the code below.

```
function uc_op_products_view_table($order) {
  dpm($order);
  $table = array(
    '#type' => 'tapir_table',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('order-pane-table')),
  );

  $table['#columns']['qty'] = array(
    'cell' => array(
      'data' => theme('uc_qty_label'),
      'class' => array('qty'),
    ),
    'weight' => 0,
  );
  $table['#columns']['product'] = array(
    'cell' => array(
      'data' => t('Product'),
      'class' => array('product'),
    ),
    'weight' => 1,
  );
```

Added by me:

```
  $table['#columns']['Vendor'] = array(
    'cell' => array(
      'data' => t('Vendor'),
      'class' => array('vendor'),
    ),
    'weight' => 1.5,
  );
```

.

```
  $table['#columns']['model'] = array(
    'cell' => array(
      'data' => t('SKU'),
      'class' => array('sku'),
    ),
    'weight' => 2,
  );
  if (user_access('administer products')) {
    $table['#columns']['cost'] = array(
      'cell' => array(
        'data' => t('Cost'),
        'class' => array('cost'),
      ),
      'weight' => 3,
    );
  }
  $table['#columns']['price'] = array(
    'cell' => array(
      'data' => t('Price'),
      'class' => array('price'),
    ),
    'weight' => 4,
  );
  $table['#columns']['total'] = array(
    'cell' => array(
      'data' => t('Total'),
      'class' => array('total'),
    ),
    'weight' => 5,
  );

  if (!empty($order->products)) {
    $build = entity_view('uc_order_product', $order->products);
```

This is the entity I want to edit. `uc_order_product` needs to have a field for Author / Vendor to make my table look right.

```
    dpm($build);
    $table['#rows'] = $build['uc_order_product'];
  }
  else {
    $table['#rows'][]['product'] = array(
      '#markup' => t('This order contains no products.'),
      '#cell_attributes' => array('colspan' => 'full'),
    );
  }

  return $table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the ugly hack I used to resolve the issue:

```
  if (!empty($order->products)) {
    $build = entity_view('uc_order_product', $order->products);
    foreach($build['uc_order_product'] as $line_item) {
      $node = node_load($line_item['#entity']->nid);
      $vendor['#markup'] = '<a href=' . url('user/' . $node->uid) . '>' . $node->uid . '</a>';
      $vendor['#cell_attributes']['class'][] = 'vendor';
      $line_item_id = $line_item['#entity']->order_product_id;
      $build['uc_order_product'][$line_item_id]['vendor'] = $vendor;
    }
    $table['#rows'] = $build['uc_order_product'];
  }
```